# Typescript Error Property 'nome' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta no backend e com o resultado guardar em um localstorage.
Estou usando Angular5.

```
valor:any;

validar(){
 this.storage.get('refresh').then(val => {
  this.loginProvider.refresh(val).subscribe(
   res => {
    this.valor=res.nome;
    this.storage.set('token', this.valor);
   },
   error => {  }
  );
 });
}
```

na hora de testar dá o erro: 
Typescript Error
Property 'nome' does not exist on type 'Object'.

alguem pode me ajudar nessa?
Valeu

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```
valor:any;

validar(){
 this.storage.get('refresh').then(val => {
  this.loginProvider.refresh(val).subscribe(
   (res:any)=> {
    this.valor=res.nome;
    this.storage.set('token', this.valor);
   },
   error => {  }
  );
 });
}
```

ou faz um map com as any que tbm funciona

```
.pipe(map(res=> res as any))
```